# How can I remove space between these two divs

Tags: html, css, css-grid

there is a space that I have between two divs that I want to remove and I just can't figure out how to do it.

Here's my html

```css
#tab-2-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.tab-2-content-bottom img {
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.tab-2-content-top {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tab-2-content-top .push {
  justify-self: right;
}

.tab-2-content-bottom {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
}

#tab-2-content .btn {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  padding: 1rem 1.8rem;
  border-radius: 0.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tab-2-content-top div {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

#tab-2-content div h2 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.tab-2-content-bottom figcaption {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}


/* the problem happens when browser width < 700px I have the following change in my media queries */

@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .tab-2-content-bottom {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    align-items: start;
  }
  .tab-2-content-top {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 0;
    max-height: 300px;
  }
  #tab-2-content div h2 {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .tab-2-content-top .push {
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: start;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="tab-2-content" class="tab-content-item">
  <div class="tab-2-content-top">
    <h2>Watch TV shows and movies anytime, anywhere — personalized for you.</h2>

    <div class="push">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Watch free for 30 days</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-2-content-bottom">
    <figure>
      <img src="img/tab-content-2-1.png" alt="#" />
      <figcaption>
        <h4>Watch on your TV</h4>
        <p>Smart TVs, PlayStation, Xbox, Chromecast, Apple TV, Blu-ray players and more.</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <img src="img/tab-content-2-2.png" alt="#" />
      <figcaption>
        <h4>Watch instantly or download for later</h4>
        <p>Available on phone and tablet, wherever you go.</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <img src="img/tab-content-2-3.png" alt="#" />
      <figcaption>
        <h4>Use any computer</h4>
        <p>Watch right on Netflix.com.</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

But I end up with a space between div .tab-2-content-top and div .tab-2-content-bottom something like you can see in the picture (the picture is put together just for clarity so don't go by it) and I have no idea how to get rid of it so the divs just sit on top of each other. Please help and thank you

Comment: PS sorry about the messy code, i'm new to this

Comment: you can use a snippet to share your and demonstrate your issue ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might reset also on smaller screens:

```
#tab-2-content{
  grid-template-rows:auto;
  }
```

```css
#tab-2-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.tab-2-content-bottom img {
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.tab-2-content-top {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tab-2-content-top .push {
  justify-self: right;
}

.tab-2-content-bottom {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
}

#tab-2-content .btn {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  padding: 1rem 1.8rem;
  border-radius: 0.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tab-2-content-top div {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

#tab-2-content div h2 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.tab-2-content-bottom figcaption {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

#tab-2-content .btn {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  padding: 1rem 1.8rem;
  border-radius: 0.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tab-2-content-top div {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

#tab-2-content div h2 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.tab-2-content-bottom figcaption {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}


/* the problem happens when browser width < 700px I have the following change in my media queries */

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {/* reset to your own value */
  #tab-2-content {
    grid-template-rows: auto;
  }
  .tab-2-content-bottom {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    align-items: start;
  }
  .tab-2-content-top {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    / grid-auto-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 0;
  }
  #tab-2-content div h2 {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .tab-2-content-top .push {
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: start;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="tab-2-content" class="tab-content-item">
  <div class="tab-2-content-top">
    <h2>Watch TV shows and movies anytime, anywhere — personalized for you.</h2>

    <div class="push">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Watch free for 30 days</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-2-content-bottom">
    <figure>
      <img src="img/tab-content-2-1.png" alt="#" />
      <figcaption>
        <h4>Watch on your TV</h4>
        <p>Smart TVs, PlayStation, Xbox, Chromecast, Apple TV, Blu-ray players and more.</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <img src="img/tab-content-2-2.png" alt="#" />
      <figcaption>
        <h4>Watch instantly or download for later</h4>
        <p>Available on phone and tablet, wherever you go.</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <img src="img/tab-content-2-3.png" alt="#" />
      <figcaption>
        <h4>Use any computer</h4>
        <p>Watch right on Netflix.com.</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but this solution will change the spacing of content inside the tab-2-content-top.

Comment: @DhruviMakvana that's the idea , each rows will get their own height instead getting the second row twice the height of the previous one . previous has about three lines, the second a single line, why should it be as tall as 6 lines for only one line of text ?

Answer (score 1):

edit: the issue is happening because in grid configuration you are trying to give 1fr of height to top-content div, and then in div..tab-2-content-top specific CSS you are trying to limit it to 300px by giving `max-height: 300px`

remove max-height and it will work as expected.

Comment: Damn, you were faster!

Comment: Thank you. If my answer has resolved your issue please accept the solution.

Comment: That's not it, the grid-gap in .tab-2-content-bottom is only between the figure elements, after removing it the space between .tab-2-content-top and .tab-2-content-bottom is still there :/

Answer (score 0):

```css
#tab-2-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.tab-2-content-bottom img {
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.tab-2-content-top {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tab-2-content-top .push {
  justify-self: right;
}

.tab-2-content-bottom {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
}

#tab-2-content .btn {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  padding: 1rem 1.8rem;
  border-radius: 0.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tab-2-content-top div {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

#tab-2-content div h2 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.tab-2-content-bottom figcaption {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}


/* the problem happens when browser width < 700px I have the following change in my media queries */

@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .tab-2-content-bottom {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    align-items: start;
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
  .tab-2-content-top {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 0;
    /*max-height: 300px;*/
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
  #tab-2-content div h2 {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .tab-2-content-top .push {
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: start;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="tab-2-content" class="tab-content-item">
  <div class="tab-2-content-top">
    <h2>Watch TV shows and movies anytime, anywhere — personalized for you.</h2>

    <div class="push">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Watch free for 30 days</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-2-content-bottom">
    <figure>
      <img src="img/tab-content-2-1.png" alt="#" />
      <figcaption>
        <h4>Watch on your TV</h4>
        <p>Smart TVs, PlayStation, Xbox, Chromecast, Apple TV, Blu-ray players and more.</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <img src="img/tab-content-2-2.png" alt="#" />
      <figcaption>
        <h4>Watch instantly or download for later</h4>
        <p>Available on phone and tablet, wherever you go.</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <img src="img/tab-content-2-3.png" alt="#" />
      <figcaption>
        <h4>Use any computer</h4>
        <p>Watch right on Netflix.com.</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```